# Login timeout with Iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe, session-timeout

I am using `IFrames` in my `asp.net` page. The page is divided into 2 vertical sections. On the left side I have links and on clicking on them the report viewer control opens in right pane. My problem is when the session times out, due to this inactivity and user clicks on some button inside Iframe, the login page opens in IFrame instead of redirecting the main window to login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following script to your login page's markup - if it's rendered in an iframe it will set the main window's url to be that of your login page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (parent.frames.length > 0) {
        parent.location.href = self.document.location;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place the below mentioend code in the code behind of the page which is to be displayed in IFrame

```
if (Session["LoginUser"] == null) {
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
    Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"), "self.parent.location='login.aspx';", true); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this code to your logon page
it will automatically set the window size whenever you are redirecting from iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript>  
if (window.frameElement && window.frameElement.nodeName == "IFRAME") {
    parent.location = self.location;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.parent.window != window) {
            window.top.location.href = window.location.href;
        }
    </script>
```